# regular expression wildcard for one single character's presence or absence

Tags: regex

This is a really noob question, but, for whatever reason I cannot find it on the googles.

I have this "^\ need\ your\ review\ and\ ap" to search for text on a screen (user interface test automation.

The word need changes to needs when the number to which it refers is 1. What is the correct regular expression to find this text whether the word is "need" or "needs". Sorry for being dense.

Comment: "needs?" - the ? quantifier matches the previous element zero or one time.

Comment: I had completely misunderstood the ? qualifier. Now I am educated. Thank you.

Comment: Can I mark your answer somehow?

Comment: I'll put it in as an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As implemented in for example .net:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/quantifiers-in-regular-expressions

The ? quantifier matches the previous element zero or one time, so the regular expression

"needs?" will match either the string "need" or the string "needs" (as the s may occur 0 or 1 times)